# link submission using jquery ajax sending null

Tags: jquery, ajax, struts2

I am submitting a link using ajax jquery On clicking like like data should be submitted and insted of like it will display dislike

I am facing followiwng problem

1) after submission it is going to next page( it should not go to next page)

2) it is sending null data

i am using following code in jquery

```
<a href="likeit" id="likeitlink">Like it</a>
var dataString = 'elementId='+ '123'+ '&elementType=' + 'games' +
     '&likedBy=' + 'abc';
 $(document).ready(function(){ 
     $('a#likeit').bind('click',function(event){
         event.preventDefault();
         $.ajax({   
             type: "POST",   
             url: "likeit", 
             dataType: "text json",
             data: dataString,   
             success: function() {   
                 $('#likeitlink').html("dislike");   
             }   
         }); 
     }); 
 });
```

in struts Action Class

```
public class LikeIt extends ActionSupport {


private String elementId;
private String elementType;
private String likedBy;

public String like() {
        System.out.println(getElementId() + ", " + getElementType() + ","
                + getLikedBy());

        return SUCCESS;
 }
```

}

In actin it is showing all values null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using Following

```
<a href="#" id="likeitlink">Like it</a>
    var dataString = 'elementId='+ '123'+ '&elementType=' + 'games' +
         '&likedBy=' + 'abc';
     $(document).ready(function(){ 
         $('#likeitlink').bind('click',function(event){
             event.preventDefault();
             $.ajax({   
                 type: "POST",   
                 url: "likeit", 
                 dataType: "json",
                 data: dataString,   
                 success: function() {   
                     $('#likeitlink').html("dislike");   
                 }   
             }); 
         }); 
     });
```

Comment: Thankyou @Elby i got the mistake

Comment: For the record, you could also clean this code up by replacing dataString with an object that has the proper key/values, jQuery will automatically convert it to properly formatted GET or POST data.